Number of ways to color $5$ vertices of a path using $7$ colors.
Say the vertices of path are $a,b,c,d$ and $e$. So according to the solution $a$ can be colored in $7$ ways, $b$ in $6$ ways, $c,d$ and $e$ also in $6$ ways. But my question is since $c$ is in between $b$ and $d$, how can it choose from $6$ colors? Shouldn't it be $5$ under normal circumstances and $6$ only when $b$ and $d$ are of same color?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The point is that if you choose colours in that order, there are always $7$ ways to colour $a$, then $6$ for $b$ (anything other than the colour of $a$), then $6$ for $c$ and so on.
If you colour $d$ before $c$, then it's true there might be $5$ or $6$ ways to colour $c$. But in that case you had $7$ choices for $d$, rather than $6$, and it balances out (if you are careful).
The point of choosing the original order is that you don't have to be careful - you always have the same number of choices at each step.
